# Does it make sense to run a java server via docker?

Tags: java, docker, server, containers, scalability

I am about to create a java server/client construct, that uses bidirectional communication via tcp sockets. For every requesting client a new thread is created. At this moment it is running on a virtual machine from a hosting service. Now i thought about using docker. But does it really make sense to switch to docker in this case? Is docker really ment to run permanent applications like a java server?

Comment: Yes, absolutely.

Comment: Of course. What do you think docker is for? Docker is an alternate to virtual machines.

Comment: Lots of places run Java services in Docker. Many also don't, because _the JVM is already a virtual machine_, and some tools (like Cloud Foundry) don't require you to add the overhead.

Comment: Affirmative, Ghost Rider.

Answer (score 1):

I'm on thin ice here but, I'm going say it anyway... If you're running a process on Linux, to most intents and purposes, the process is running in a container.

Containers are "sugar" atop intrinsic Linux kernel features (namespaces, cgroups etc.). Solutions including Docker Engine mostly made these -- somewhat arcane -- capabilities of the kernel available more broadly available | easier to use.

Containers and VMs are very distinct technologies. Extending the above, you can run VMs in Containers and -- you're almost always -- running Containers in VMs.

It's containers all the way down :-)

To answer your question directly: you are already running your Java server in a container and it's running on a VM. You may decide to do two things but please read up more on each before deciding:

- Add Docker (Engine) into your existing VM (if it's not already there) as a way to more easily manage your Java server as a Docker container. **Benefits**: unclear but see below.
- Extract the Java server from the VM (!) and run the server instead as a Docker container. **Benefits**: unclear; **Consequence**: may not be possible with your hosting company; potential security concerns; no well-defined benefits; etc.

One benefit for you in using containers and deploying containers to your existing hosting provider (and continuing to use their VMs) is that you would be able to build and test in locations other than your hosting provider and be (mostly) guaranteed that a container image that worked during build and test will also work on your hosting service provider in production.

HTH!